# What's the difference between a zero client and a thin client when it comes to virtual desktops?

Tags: virtualization

Do these terms mean someone can boot a machine over the network?  What is on the hard drive of the machine?  I have seen Dell and Xen and others.  I'm not getting it.  Thanks.

Can you run an OS remotely like that?  Office applications, etc?

Comment: Yes you can remote into these clients if you set it up to support it and share the display but most are limited to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero clients do have some memory but no operating system and no hard disk, just a firmware able to drive a graphic card, a NIC, and USB ports (keyboard, mouse).  Everything else is running elsewhere over the network.

Answer (score 1):

zero clients have no hard disks unlike thin clients which can store OS files and some configuration in its flash memory. See http://searchvirtualdesktop.techtarget.com/definition/zero-client for more info

Comment: So on a thin client, what is on there?  For example, I have Windows 7 VM I made with xen (not really, just for the question).  What is on the physical machine?

Comment: It has the common interfaces including USB, VGA, graphic card, Audio in and out and most importantly the NIC(Network Interface Card) and the flash memory.